# Error starting SCDF plugin in Ambari

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow

I installed SCDF using Ambari, but I cannot seem to successfully start Spring Cloud Dataflow server. I am getting the following output from the log:

```
03:07:30.592 [main] ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Application startup failed
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load property source from location 'file:/etc/scdf/conf//servers.yml'
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader.loadIntoGroup(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:465)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader.load(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:432)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader.load(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:371)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener.addPropertySources(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:214)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener.postProcessEnvironment(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:184)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener.onApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:171)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:157)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:167)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:122)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:74)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:54)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:325)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:296)
    at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:134)
    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.bootstrapServiceContext(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:175)
    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:98)
    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:64)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:167)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:122)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:74)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:54)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:325)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:296)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107)
    at org.springframework.cloud.dataflow.server.yarn.YarnDataFlowServer.main(YarnDataFlowServer.java:34)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51)
Caused by: org.yaml.snakeyaml.parser.ParserException: while parsing a block mapping
 in 'reader', line 51, column 5:
        fsUri: hdfs://hdp.kgarza.com:8020
        ^
expected <block end>, but found Scalar
 in 'reader', line 57, column 46:
     ... cationClasspath: {{hadoop_home}}/conf,{{hadoop_home}}/*,{{hadoop ... 
                                         ^

    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.parser.ParserImpl$ParseBlockMappingKey.produce(ParserImpl.java:569)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.parser.ParserImpl.peekEvent(ParserImpl.java:157)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.parser.ParserImpl.checkEvent(ParserImpl.java:147)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.composer.Composer.composeMappingNode(Composer.java:224)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.composer.Composer.composeNode(Composer.java:155)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.composer.Composer.composeValueNode(Composer.java:246)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.composer.Composer.composeMappingChildren(Composer.java:237)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.composer.Composer.composeMappingNode(Composer.java:225)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.composer.Composer.composeNode(Composer.java:155)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.composer.Composer.composeValueNode(Composer.java:246)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.composer.Composer.composeMappingChildren(Composer.java:237)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.composer.Composer.composeMappingNode(Composer.java:225)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.composer.Composer.composeNode(Composer.java:155)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.composer.Composer.composeDocument(Composer.java:122)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.composer.Composer.getNode(Composer.java:84)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.BaseConstructor.getData(BaseConstructor.java:104)
    at org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml$1.next(Yaml.java:471)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.YamlProcessor.process(YamlProcessor.java:160)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.YamlProcessor.process(YamlProcessor.java:138)
    at org.springframework.boot.env.YamlPropertySourceLoader$Processor.process(YamlPropertySourceLoader.java:101)
    at org.springframework.boot.env.YamlPropertySourceLoader.load(YamlPropertySourceLoader.java:58)
    at org.springframework.boot.env.PropertySourcesLoader.load(PropertySourcesLoader.java:127)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader.doLoadIntoGroup(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:479)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader.loadIntoGroup(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:462)
    ... 35 common frames omitted
```

Here is my servers.yml configuration:

```
# Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
# contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
# this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
# The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
# (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
# the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.


---
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      kafka:
        binder:
          brokers: 192.168.1.43:6667
          zkNodes: 192.168.1.43:2181

---
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:h2:tcp://hdp.kgarza.com:19092/dataflow
    username: sa
    password:
    driverClassName: org.h2.Driver

---
spring:
  cloud:
    dataflow:
      metrics:
        collector:
          uri: http://hdp.kgarza.com:18080
    stream:
      bindings:
        applicationMetrics:
          destination: metrics
---
dataflow:
  uri: http://hdp.kgarza.com:9393
spring:
  hadoop:
    fsUri: hdfs://hdp.kgarza.com:8020
    resourceManagerAddress: hdp.kgarza.com:8050
    resourceManagerHost: hdp.kgarza.com
    resourceManagerPort: 8050
    resourceManagerSchedulerAddress: hdp.kgarza.com:8030
    jobHistoryAddress: hdp.kgarza.com:10020
    yarnApplicationClasspath: {{hadoop_home}}/conf,{{hadoop_home}}/*,{{hadoop_home}}/lib/*,/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-hdfs-client/*,/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-hdfs-client/lib/*,/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-yarn-client/*,/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-yarn-client/lib/*,/usr/hdp/current/ext/hadoop/*
    config:
      yarn.resourcemanager.scheduler.address: hdp.kgarza.com:8030
      mapreduce.application.framework.path: /hdp/apps/2.6.0.3-8/mapreduce/mapreduce.tar.gz#mr-framework
      mapreduce.application.classpath: $PWD/mr-framework/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/*:$PWD/mr-framework/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/*:$PWD/mr-framework/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/*:$PWD/mr-framework/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/*:$PWD/mr-framework/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/*:$PWD/mr-framework/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/*:$PWD/mr-framework/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/*:$PWD/mr-framework/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/*:$PWD/mr-framework/hadoop/share/hadoop/tools/lib/*:/usr/hdp/2.6.0.3-8/hadoop/lib/hadoop-lzo-0.6.0.2.6.0.3-8.jar:/etc/hadoop/conf/secure:/usr/hdp/current/ext/hadoop/*

---
dataflow.server.port : 9393
deployer.yarn.app.baseDir : '/dataflow'
h2.server.port : 19092
maven.remoteRepositories.springRepo.url : 'https://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot'
metrics.collector.binder : 'kafka-10'
metrics.collector.channel : 'metrics'
metrics.collector.enabled : true
metrics.collector.server.port : 18080
spring.cloud.deployer.yarn.app.streamappmaster.javaOpts : '-Xms512m -Xmx512m'
spring.cloud.deployer.yarn.app.streamappmaster.memory : 1024
spring.cloud.deployer.yarn.app.streamcontainer.javaOpts : '-Xms512m -Xmx512m'
spring.cloud.deployer.yarn.app.streamcontainer.memory : 1024
spring.cloud.deployer.yarn.app.taskappmaster.javaOpts : '-Xms512m -Xmx512m'
spring.cloud.deployer.yarn.app.taskappmaster.memory : 1024
spring.cloud.deployer.yarn.app.taskcontainer.javaOpts : '-Xms512m -Xmx512m'
spring.cloud.deployer.yarn.app.taskcontainer.memory : 1024
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.brokers : '192.168.1.43:6667'
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.zkNodes : '192.168.1.43:2181'
spring.rabbitmq.password : 'guest'
spring.rabbitmq.username : 'guest'
```

It seems like the problem is related with the configuration in the servers.yml on line 51 according to the logs, but I cannot see what it is that is wrong.

edit:
Upon further review it seems that there is an error in the servers.yml in the line 
    yarnApplicationClasspath: {{hadoop_home}}/conf,{{hadoop_home}}/*,{{hadoop_home}}/lib/*,/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-hdfs-client/*,/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-hdfs-client/lib/*,/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-yarn-client/*,/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-yarn-client/lib/*,/usr/hdp/current/ext/hadoop/*

I edited the file to replace the {{hadoop_home}} variable, but it seems that it gets overridden everytime I restart the scdf server from ambari.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed `yarnApplicationClasspath: {{hadoop_home}}` looks to be wrong.

Source for that is `yarnApplicationClasspath: {{yarn_app_classpath}}` and value is coming from `yarn_app_classpath = config['configurations']['yarn-site']['yarn.application.classpath']`.

Could you check what you actually have in `yarn-site` configs under ambari's yarn service?

i.e I have something like

```
<property>
  <name>yarn.application.classpath</name>
  <value>$HADOOP_CONF_DIR,/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-client/*,/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-client/lib/*,/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-hdfs-client/*,/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-hdfs-client/lib/*,/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-yarn-client/*,/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-yarn-client/lib/*</value>
</property>
```